# How to make a single character out of many parts?

Tags: modeling, rigify

I have created a low poly model that I'm attempting to rig. Using rigify, I notice certain aspects of the model don't move, namely the legs. I believe this is because the joints, namely the torso connecting to the legs, is not fully connected by  a legit joint. I've seen that rigify works much better on solid models. Is there a way to fix my issue? Perhaps by making it a fully connected model, or anything else? [image: low poly model where legs don't rig]

Comment: Weights play nicer if you join them all together then separate after making the weights

Comment: So would you say using weights would be helpful in correcting this issue? Do you have any reccomendations?

Comment: Well since the characters split into pieces that way, you could always just put each piece to different bones